# Issue with display all results from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use this SQL query to get results from different tables

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT gtem.gname AS itmnme, gvendor.gname AS vendor, gtem.col AS qty
FROM gpopackageline
LEFT JOIN gpo ON gpo.gpoid = gpopackageline.gpoid
LEFT JOIN gtem ON gpopackageline.gtemid = gtem.gtemid
LEFT JOIN gvendor ON gitem.gvendorid = gvendor.gvendorid
WHERE gpopackageline.gpoid='".$sdo['swelid']."' ";
$row = dblib_get_row_list($sql);
?>
<td class="contents51" width="100%"><?=$row['itmnme']?> </td>
<td class="contents51" width="100%"><?=$row['vendor']?> </td>
<td class="contents51" width="100%"><?=$row['qty']?> </td>
```

Issue is I get only 1 and first result printed.
When i test query in phpmyadmin I get all the results
Does anyboby can help with this
Thank You

Comment: How does your `dblib_get_row_list` function look like?

Comment: What is "dblib_get_row_list"?

Comment: Maybe you need a cycle for each $row?

Comment: I think it needs a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your results, either by a `while`, or `foreach` - depending on your logic.

***For example***

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT gtem.gname AS itmnme, gvendor.gname AS vendor, gtem.col AS qty
FROM gpopackageline
LEFT JOIN gpo ON gpo.gpoid = gpopackageline.gpoid
LEFT JOIN gtem ON gpopackageline.gtemid = gtem.gtemid
LEFT JOIN gvendor ON gitem.gvendorid = gvendor.gvendorid
WHERE gpopackageline.gpoid='".$sdo['swelid']."' ";
$getRows = dblib_get_row_list($sql);  //Assuming this returns everything in an assoc array
foreach($getRows as $row) {
?>
<td class="contents51" width="100%"><?=$row['itmnme']?> </td>
<td class="contents51" width="100%"><?=$row['vendor']?> </td>
<td class="contents51" width="100%"><?=$row['qty']?> </td>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: No problem at all :) Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your dblib_get_row_list is return. If it returns array then it should work as you expected.

```
 <?
    $sql = "SELECT gtem.gname AS itmnme, gvendor.gname AS vendor, gtem.col AS qty
    FROM gpopackageline
    LEFT JOIN gpo ON gpo.gpoid = gpopackageline.gpoid
    LEFT JOIN gtem ON gpopackageline.gtemid = gtem.gtemid
    LEFT JOIN gvendor ON gitem.gvendorid = gvendor.gvendorid
    WHERE gpopackageline.gpoid='".$sdo['swelid']."' ";
    $result = dblib_get_row_list($sql);
    foreach($result as $row ){
    echo "<td class='contents51' width='100%'>".$row['itmnme']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='contents51' width='100%'>".$row['vendor']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='contents51' width='100%'>".$row['qty']."</td>";

    }
```